# Unirest throws class not found exception

Tags: java, unirest

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/concurrent/FutureCallback
>       at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
>       at iezon.main.WebSocket.getAllApps(WebSocket.java:21)
>       at iezon.main.Init.(Init.java:16)
>       at iezon.main.Init.main(Init.java:27)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.concurrent.FutureCallback
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       ... 4 more

My current code is:

```
package iezon.main;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;

import iezon.interfaces.options.InterfaceController;

public class WebSocket {
    public WebSocket() {

    }

    public void getAllApps() {
        try {
            HttpResponse<JsonNode> request = Unirest.get("https://iezontechnologywebapp.000webhostapp.com/api/store/get").asJson();
            JSONArray response = request.getBody().getArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                  // TODO: Load apps properly this is just a test dialog to show they loaded
                  InterfaceController.showDialog(new Object[] {
                      object.getString("name"),
                      object.getString("description")
                  }, "Apps loaded");
                }
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding httpclient-4.3.3.jar to the buildpath as well as commons-io-2.5.jar but neither has fixed the issue, I have checked documentation but doesn't say I need any other libraries to run Unirest

Comment: You need the apache httpcore library for this class.

Comment: I receive this error now: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/nio/reactor/IOReactorException` @skandigraun

Comment: Haha. You also need httpcore-nio lib apparently :) And maybe this is not the last.